# Bind Ready Function and Resize Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind, jquery-events

In jQuery, is it possible to somehow "bind" an action to both the `ready` function and a `resize` event? I'm trying to add/remove classes on resize and I want the initial class state to be there on ready.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to trigger the `resize` event immediately after binding it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // code to run on resize
    }).resize(); // trigger resize handlers
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function onresize()
{
  // do your stuff here
}

// called on "init"
onresize();

// called when window is resized
$(window).resize(function(){ onresize(); });
```